# Unable to bind Ctrl+Click in IntelliJ

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, window-managers

I am trying to set `^Click` as my binding for 'GoTo' in 'Main Menu | Navigate" as I have by default on Linux/Windows.

When I right click select "Add Mouse Shortcut" and open the binding setup window, holding control and clicking appears to do nothing, and likewise holding control and another non-modifier key also does nothing. Oddly enough, I am able to combine control with other modifiers (e.g. Ctrl+Shift+Click).

Comment: I would have tagged this question with `[yabai]`, seeing as other window managers such as `i3` have their own tag, however that tag doesn't exist and I'm unable to create tags. I guess `yabai` might be too obscure to merit its own tag at this time. This question is still applicable to most other WMs though, I think.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour was a result of my window manager, `yabai`, and not IntelliJ. In my `yabairc` I had my mouse modifier key set to `ctrl`:

```
yabai -m config mouse_modifier ctrl
```

After unsetting this, I am able to bind `^Click` in IntelliJ.